# Lower/Upper bounds for $ \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom ni x^i $

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Are there good lower/upper bounds for 
$ \sum\limits_{i = 0}^k {\left( \begin{array}{l} n \\  i \\  \end{array} \right)x^i } $ where $0<x<1$, $k \ll n$?

Comment: The ratio of two consequtive summands is $\frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}}=\frac{n-i+1}{i}x$ is unimodular. So you'll easily find the largest summand. And it is an upper bound for the whole sum (up to some constant), because another terms decrease not slower than geometric progression.

Comment: BTW you can typeset binomial coefficient as `\binom ni` $\binom ni$. If you want bigger size, you can use `\dbinom ni` $\dbinom ni`$. (But I would not recommend the latter in the title.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov I doubt about geometric progression. Say, if $x=k/n$, the sum is approximately 1/2, but each summand is much less.

Comment: (Sorry, I was thinking about a different sum $\sum \binom{n}i x^i (1-x)^{n-i}$, which is reduced to this sum and vice versa via introducying $x/(1-x)$ as a new variable).

Comment: related to :https://mathoverflow.net/q/55585/51189

Answer (score 7):

Write $x=p/(1-p)$ and then
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ni x^i = (1-p)^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ni p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
The last sum is the cumulative binomial distribution, which has no exact formula (except as a special function) but a large literature on bounds.  It is quite a common topic on Mathoverflow, see these for example:
[ref1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220030/normal-approximation-of-tail-probability-in-binomial-distribution) [ref2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149440/asymptotic-behaviour-of-binomial-sum) [ref3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201530/partial-sum-of-the-binomial-theorem?rq=1) [ref4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93744/estimating-a-partial-sum-of-weighted-binomial-coefficients) [ref5](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55585/lower-bound-for-sum-of-binomial-coefficients)

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=\frac{x}{1+x}$ and $q=\frac{1}{1+x}$, and thus
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} x^i=(1+x)^n\sum_{i=n-k}^n  \binom{n}{i} p^{n-i} q^i.$$
Then for $k<np$ [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) gives
$$\sum_{i=n-k}^n  \binom{n}{i} p^{n-i} q^i \le \left( \frac{nq}{n-k}\right)^{n-k} e^{np-k}.$$
That is,
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} x^i \le (1+x)^k \left( \frac{n}{n-k}\right)^{n-k} e^{\frac{(n-k)x-k}{1+x}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :for lower Bound we have for $k> 1$:$ (1+\frac{1}{k})^k \leq (e^{1/k})^k =e ,0<x=1/k<1$ , and $1/k  << k $